# A polynomial expansion question

Tags: probability, polynomials

Consider a polynomial $g(X) = ((1+X)^k + (1-X)^k)^m$, where $k$ is a fixed integer larger than $1$ and $m\rightarrow\infty$. Does there exist a method to approximate or (reasonably) upper bound the coefficients of $g(X)$? I have tried many ways but still no luck. However, I tried to run computer program for small $n$, and I found the distribution of the coefficients is somewhat Gaussian-like with mean about $m/2$ so that I think there might be some intelligent way to approximate $g(X)$.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no upper bound, as you have to use the multinomial formula. If $r$ is the number of terms on developing $(1+X)^k+(1-X)^k$ ($r=\Bigl\lfloor\frac k2\Bigr\rfloor+1$), the multinomial coefficients have the form:
$$\frac{m!}{i_1!\:i_2!\:\dotsm\: i_r!}, \quad i_1+i_2+i_r=m$$
and they can be arbitrarily large as $m\to \infty$.

Comment: Thanks. I had tried this way, but it involves to solve non-negative solutions of an equation such that I can not easily use it in my other works.